# How do you re-run an already executed query from 'Query History' pgadmin?

Tags: pgadmin-4

[image: pgAmind 4 query tool]

As in pgAdmin 4 screenshot, one can see a list of recently executed queries.

The play button, **Execute / Refresh(F5)** tool executes the most recent query instead of the selected/highlighted one.

I know I can click on a query, and from the right side pane click on copy and go to the  **Query Editor** to run it.

My question is, is there a shortcut or some options using GUI in pgAdmin 4 to re-run the query of my choice (**selected/highlighted query**) from history?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot execute this in View/Edit table mode. However, you can copy the SQL and open a new query tool, paste the query and run it.